# Why isn't my code working for scanf and a few others?

Tags: visual-c++

So, I'm currently attempting a small project in a community college class. For this code, I used one example as a template to make mine, but for some reason it just won't function no matter what I try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include stdio.h

int main(){
    /*Declaration of Input and Output variables*/
    float width, height, rectangle; /*width and height are the input numbers, rectangle is the output*/
    /*Prepare option of input*/
    printf("Please type in the width: "); /*width input*/

    scanf("%f", &width);

    printf("Please type in the height: "); /*height input*/

    scanf("%f", & height);

    /*prepare the output*/
    rectangle = width * height; 
    /*display the results*/
    printf("Going by the formula w * h, %f times %f gives: % f\n", rectangle);

    return 0;
}
```

and the following errors are provided:
[The errors in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNY9V.png)
Any ideas on what I could do to fix it? Keep in mind, the int main() runs fine, I just can't get scanf to work because it was declared "unsafe" despite being the focus of input in this project.

Comment: You need share the errors, so that we can understand the problem.

Comment: `#include stdio.h` (without quotes or angle brackets around the file name) is no a valid syntax.

Comment: `% f` (with a space in between) is not a valid format specifier.

Comment: The format string in the last `printf` call contains three format specifiers (assuming the last one of `% f` is a typo and the space is not actually there), and so should be followed by three arguments; but only one is provided.